# Cannot find module 'core-js/...' even though @babel/polyfill is installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, babeljs, babel-polyfill

We are using `padStart`.

To support earlier version of Node we are using babel and its `@babel/preset-env` preset:

```
[
  "@babel/preset-env",
  {
    targets: {
      node: "6.11.5"
    },
    // Support padStart et cetera
    useBuiltIns: "usage"
  }
]
```

[`useBuiltIns`](https://new.babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html#usebuiltins) automatically brings in the `padStart` polyfill.

This works when we include `core-js` in our dependencies. This doesn't work when we include only `@babel/polyfill` in our dependencies. This is the error message on deploy to Google Firebase Functions:

> Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es7.string.pad-start'

That message goes away when we explicitly install `core-js`.

**Why do we need to include `core-js` explicitly when `@babel/polyfill` includes it?**

This is how we installed `@babel/polyfill` and `core-js`.

```
npm install @babel/polyfill --save
npm install core-js --save
```

Comment: Seems related to [this note](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#tc39-proposals)

Comment: It does indeed @bigless. Nice find.